# Java Applet JFileChooser button issue?

Tags: java, swing, applet, jfilechooser

```
     if ("Analyze Text File".equals(command)) {
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
    if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File[] files = chooser.getSelectedFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                String text = sb.toString();
                Map<Integer, Integer> counts = getCounts(text)
                HistogramPanel panel = new HistogramPanel(width, counts, height, horizon
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to get a `JFileChooser` to pop up once I click my *"Analyze to text"* button, which then will allow the user to select a text file which will be processed with my code and output a bar chart.
Everything is working except the button for some reason. If anyone can help it will be appreciated.

```
    // Object textfile = null; 
  else if("Text".equals(command)) {
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
          "txt", "text", "docx");
      chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
 int returnVal = JFileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
       if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
           File file = JFileChooser.getSelectedFile();
           Map<Integer, Integer> counts = getCounts(Stext);
           int width = counts.size() * BAR
           int horizon = height - 25;
           HistogramPanel panel = new HistogramPanel(width, counts, height, horizon);

       }
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "once I click my **"Analyze to text"** button,"

Could be maybe the actionCommand is not `"Text"` and you should be checking if `"Analyze to text"`

> `if ("Text".equals(command)) {` → `if ("Analyze to Text".equals(command)) {`
>
> `// or whatever the text/actionCommand of your button is`

Another seemingly obvious problem, is you have declared `JFileChooser chooser` but you're trying to access `filechooser`

---

**UPDATE**

Use this code. Change your button text back. If it doesn't work, then you changed something else in your code, and I can't help, because this works fine for me.

```
    if ("Analyze Text File".equals(command)) {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        int result = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            try {
                File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                String text = sb.toString();
                Map<Integer, Integer> counts = getCounts(text);
                int width = counts.size() * BAR_WIDTH;
                int max = maxCount(counts);
                int height = max * INCREMENT + 100;
                int horizon = height - 25;
                HistogramPanel panel = new HistogramPanel(width, counts, height, horizon);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I changed my "analyze to text" button name to "Text" for the mean while, it isnt working still.

Comment: What's not working, it's not popping up? What about the file chooser variable descrepency?

Comment: i have changed the filechooser to Jfilechooser just how i have declared it but it still doesnt work

Comment: no it doesnt pop up, i get errors like:
at assignment_work.actionPerformed(assignment_work.java:290)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)

Comment: What errors? You need to be specific with problems.

Comment: Do you not know how to use variables? Why are you using `JFileChooser.showOpenDialog`. Do you even know the difference between that and `chooser.showOpenDialog`?

Comment: in my code when i changed the JFilechooser.showOpenDialog to chooser.showOpenDialog it opens up the Jfilechooser but when i try selecting a txt file it comes with these errors:

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at assignment_work.getCounts(assignment_work.java:199)
 at assignment_work.actionPerformed(assignment_work.java:294)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)

Comment: Probably because you changed the name of the button.

Comment: i changed that back to how it was

Comment: The I have above is based on the the code from your previous post. All I did was add this code and it works. I had this done when we first talked, I just didn't want to give you the answer, so would learn something. So like I said, if this doesn't work, then you changed something else, And with _just_ the information your provided, I can't help you.

Comment: i did fix it thank you, i am now researching on how to load 2 text files simultaneously and for it to bring up the histogram for both files, so it will pop up 2 histograms side by side instead of one

Comment: i have had a go on loading 2 files, im only getting 1 error on the bufferedreader, please see updated code above, thanks

Comment: hi, sorry to bother you again, i have managed to get the jfilechooser to read in 2 text files but im unsure on how to open 2 panels side by side, at the moment it is opening one histogram panel first then when clicked ok the second text file histogram opens? i will update the code above

Comment: it isnt allowing me to ask a new question? says it is no longer accepting questions from this account :/

Comment: Hi please look at 'Java histogram in 2 windows from JFileChooser' question, i have posted from my friends account, thanks

Comment: @user3356827 see the post.